# What is an RStudio Addin that helps to create headers to better structure code

Tags: r, rstudio

I used to rely on an RStudio Addin where one entered a headline as text, and then it automatically created standardized formatted header for the code. It provided three types of headers (if I recall correctly). So, one could enter "test headline" and then get an automated headline which was a combination of hashtags and hyphens that helped to structure the code.

I do not know the name of the Addin and when I reinstalled R it was not available anymore. Do you know the name of that RStudio Addin or one with a similar functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta ?

Comment: Not what I meant. Sorry, description might have been bad. I meant how to comment headers as part of the code.